# How to get src/main/resources path from Java

Tags: java, resources, classpath

I have some stuff under `src/main/resources` path.
Specifically I have a folder with report templates called reports.

I understand that when the application is deployed/run all files and folders under `src/main/resources` go to the classpath, namely my project's `WEB-INF/classes`.

This means that a folder `WEB-INF/classes/reports` will be created in my server.

Now I want to access my reports **as paths**, not as inputstream, because my reporting code in java supports a filepath and not an inputstream. So I have to be able to get the `WEB-INF/classes/reports` absolute path (or relative, I don't care as long as it is right).

Reading some answers regarding similar questions, I have already tried the following things:

1. `getClass().getResource(".").getPath();` --> this returns the exact path of the class I am currently at in my classpath, namely: `C:\Tools\JBoss Application Server 7.1.1\standalone\deployments\myProject.war\WEB-INF\classes\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd`
2. `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();` --> this returns: `C:\Tools\JBoss Application Server 7.1.1\modules\sun\jdk\main\service-loader-resources`, which is completely irrelevant.

I want something to return `C:\Tools\JBoss Application Server 7.1.1\standalone\deployments\myProject.war\WEB-INF\classes`

If it is not possible, I will get the first path and go as many folders back as needed to reach classes folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to access the reports as paths?

Comment: Actually it is not necessary. Jasper supports Inputstream also. If you have something to suggest feel free. I am searching for a general solution of where to put files. For example I would also like to know where does one usually put PDF output reports in a Web Java Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [ServletContext.getRealPath(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF")
```